# Vue 3 - 'this' references methods and not app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm having trouble creating a method to remove an item from an array using Vue 3. The method executes properly, but 'this' refers to 'methods.'

```
<div id="blog-posts-demo">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <blog-post class="col-4"
                       v-for="post in posts"
                       v-bind:id="post.id"
                       v-bind:key="post.id"
                       v-bind:title="post.title">
            </blog-post>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button onclick="App.methods.remove(3)">
    Delete Item
</button>

@section Scripts {

    @*<script src="~/js/signlartest.js"></script>*@

    <script src="~/js/vue/vue.global.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var App = {
            data() {
                return {
                    name: 'Cards',
                    posts: [
                        { id: 1, title: 'Card 1' },
                        { id: 2, title: 'Card 2' },
                        { id: 3, title: 'Card 3' },
                        { id: 4, title: 'Card 4' },
                        { id: 5, title: 'Card 5' },
                        { id: 6, title: 'Card 6' },
                        { id: 7, title: 'Card 7' },
                        { id: 8, title: 'Card 8' },
                        { id: 9, title: 'Card 9' },
                        { id: 10, title: 'Card 10' }
                    ]
                }
            },
            methods: {
                remove(itemId) {
                    console.log('this: ' + this);
                    console.log('app.name ' + App.name);
                    console.log('itemId ' + itemId);
                }
            }
        }

        const app = Vue.createApp(App);

        app.component('blog-post', {
            props: ['title', 'id'],
            template: `
<div class='card'>
    <h4>
        {{ title }}
    </h4>
</div>
`
        })

        app.mount('#blog-posts-demo')

    </script>

}
```

Here's the output when I click the Delete Item button:

this: [object Object]

(index):104 app.name undefined

(index):105 itemId 3

According to all documentation and examples I've found, in its current context 'this' should refer to the data object. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

My ultimate goal is to be able to externally add/remove/update models managed by Vue.

Thank you!

Comment: you console.log App.name ... what does `this` have to do with it? what is `this.name` (instead of `App.name`)

Comment: That was just an attempt at trying to troubleshoot and find a way to reference properties of the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're bypassing Vue when you call `remove` like that. To get the correct `this` binding you need to go via a component instance.

You can grab the root component instance returned by `mount`. Something like this:

```js
const vm = app.mount('#blog-posts-demo')
```

So long as you create `vm` globally you can then call `vm.remove(3)` in your `onclick`.